# Is it possible how change the gray highlight color in select mutiple after out of focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible how change the gray highlight color in select mutiple after out of focus ?

[image]

Comment: No. It's controlled by the OS.

Comment: Oh I see thank for help   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is:

```
select[multiple] option:checked {
  ...
}
```

If you only want to change the grey color, use this:

```
select[multiple]:not(:focus) option:checked {
  ...
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/vzDvK/379/

Comment: I have new problem . the method  doesn't work in safari . How can I fix this problem ?